# Как задаётся кодировка текстового файла и как notePad++ определяет кодировку?

Tags: php, linux, windows, delphi

Давно уже знаю что на PHP взять любой файл и открыть его через `file_get_contents` (причём не важно с диска или по ссылке в Интернет) а затем сохранить через `fopen fwrite` и он не будет повреждённым.

Стал копаться с файлами в Delphi и заметил что если при сохранении в текстовый файл использовать `file: array of byte` и записать 4 байта соответствующие слову `text`, то такой файл не получится открыть в NotePad, вернее он откроется как бинарный и текст в нём читаться не будет.

Вот ещё какой момент, создаём к примеру 2 текстовых файла с помощью NotePad++ в оба пишем слово text, только один файл в ANSI а другой в UTF-8 если теперь прочитать оба файла с помощью языка программирования то оба файла имеют длину 4 байта и одинаковые коды символов. Вот только NotePad откуда то знает, что один в кодировке ANSI а другой в UTF-8.

Я уже начал думать что кодировка текстового файла хранится в операционной системе где то отдельно от файла. Но кажется нет, поскольку если взять 2 эти файла и переместить на другой комп, не важно по e-mail или через FTP то NotePad++ на другом компе всё равно определит что кодировка одного файла UTF-8 а другого ANSI. Хотя оба хранят всё те же одинаковые 4 байта информации.

В Интернет смотрел информацию, написано что кодировка текстовых файлов определяется только телом символов в нём содержащихся, но я же записываю слово text и ничего большего, а кодировка символов этого слова в UTF-8 и ANSI одинаковая. Возможно я упустил из внимания какой то важный момент. Как тогда NotePad++ понимает у какого текстового файла кодировка UTF-8 а у какого ANSI? И есть ли какие то особенности у бинарных файлов? Может быть какие то особые заголовки?

Comment: http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2007/04/22/2239345.html вот так определяет notepad

Comment: Если файлы действительно идентичны, то Notepad++ (v7.8.5) всегда определяет, что у файла кодировка UTF-8.

Comment: Для работы с файлами в Delphi используйте потоки [TFileStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Classes.TFileStream.Create), [TMemoryStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TMemoryStream) с ручным перекодированием строк в нужную кодировку, либо [TStreamReader\TStreamWriter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TStreamWriter.Create), с автоматической перекодировкой (нужная кодировка файла указывается при создании потока).

Comment: @zed и автор, смотрите первый комментарий. Если редактор написан правильно, то он должен следовать BOM.

Comment: @0andriy В вопросе речь про UTF-8 без BOM и в таком случае отличить эту кодировку от ANSI можно только эвристическими методами.